# How to convert String formatted date to timestamp in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a string in this format.

`var stringDate = '27-04-2021 19:45' //dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm`

I want to convert this String date to Timestamp (millisecondsSinceEpoch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

getCustomFormattedDateTime(String givenDateTime, String dateFormat) {
    // dateFormat = 'MM/dd/yy';
    final DateTime docDateTime = DateTime.parse(givenDateTime);
    return DateFormat(dateFormat).format(docDateTime);
}
```

You can use this method

```
getCustomFormattedDateTime('2021-02-15T18:42:49.608466Z', 'MM/dd/yy');
```

Result:

02/15/21

Comment: I need time and date

Comment: try this one getCustomFormattedDateTime('2021-02-15T18:42:49.608466Z', 'MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss a');